# Presto on Search of normal select query[non partitioned hive table] gives Column $path doesn't exist in table <Table> in database default

Tags: hive, presto

We have a non partitioned table - xx_table in hive on querying it gives proper response. on Presto with connection to hive , gives below error response. [Presto version : presto_0.180]

```
presto:default> select * from xx_table;
```

> Query 20210722_123707_00059_42bza failed: Column $path doesn't exist
> in table xx_table in database default

```
presto:default> show create table xx_table;
   
----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE hive.default.xx_table (
    a bigint,
    b timestamp,
    c timestamp,
    d bigint,
    e bigint,
    f bigint,
    g varchar,
    h timestamp,
    i bigint,
    j timestamp,
    k bigint
 )
 WITH (
    format = 'ORC'
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try to compute statistics in Hive:

```
ANALYZE TABLE .... COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS
```

It seems it is this bug: [#8380](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8380)
You can try also to upgrade to 0.183 or higher